Synchronous URL loading of IMAGE_LINK should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness
i'm trying to get the dimensions of the image from it's URL. i wanted to use this piece of code and modify it according to my needs. here's what the final code looks like:
    func imageDimensions(url: String) -> CGFloat {
    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(URL(string: url)! as CFURL, nil) {
        if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
            let pixelWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
            let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int
            if pixelWidth > pixelHeight {
                return 1.91
            } else if pixelWidth < pixelHeight {
                return 0.8
            } else {
                return 1
            }
        }
    }
    return 1
}

however this is giving me a

Synchronous URL loading of IMAGE_LINK should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

error
how can i use URLSession here in order to switch to async?
tested with Swift 5.1 and XCode 15.3

Seeing CGImageSourceCreateWithURL, I guess it's a local resource. I'd wrap that method inside a background thread instead.
